# AWS DynamoDB is charging me even if my usage is within the free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to AWS. Pardon me if this question is too dumb.

According to [AWS' documentation on the free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all), using DynamoDB tables with the provisioned mode is free **up to 25WCU/RCU per region**. Here is a table that I've been using over the last 2 to 3 weeks.

[image]

As you can see, both RCU and WCU have 25 capacity units. I have another DynamoDB table with exact the same table capacity in provision mode.

[image]

... then, how come I was charged for using DynamoDB tables? Should I contact AWS's customer service?

Comment: What is surprising here? You used up all your free Tier on one table and the other one is fully billed!?

Comment: The Free Tier for DynamoDB would cover a **total** of 25 WCUs and 25 RCUs. You are consuming twice as much with two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the first 25 RCU/WCU in an account are free...

You could have 1 table provisioned at 25 RCU/WCU
or 25 tables provisioned at 1 RCU/WCU.

You've used up your free tier with the first table provisioned at 25 RCU/WCU, so you pay the full price for the second one.

Comment: Just a question, if I put it on on-demand mode instead of provisioned mode knowing full well that I'll never exceed the free 200M requests, will I not get charged then? (My average is 1000 requests between reads and writes a month).

Comment: DDB on-demand mode isn't included in the free tier of DDB.